# JS make element move by applying .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to make an element move on arrow press by applying .css() but its not working at all and I cant figure out why. The exactly same code is working perfectly with JQ animate(). Can you explain me why the .css is not working ? I know there are better ways to do this but I'm just curious why its not attaching the top property.Below is the code with animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').keydown(function() {
        if (event.which == 38)
        {
            $('div').animate({top:'-=10px'},'fast');
        }
        else if (event.which == 40)
        {
            $('div').animate({top:'+=10px'},'fast');
        }
        else if (event.which == 37)
        {
            $('div').animate({left:'-=10px'},'fast');
        }
        else if (event.which == 39)
        {
            $('div').animate({left:'+=10px'},'fast');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: If you're just using the `css()` function specify `top` or `left` values, the target element must have a `position` property capable of receiving such styles, for example: `position: absolute`.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/t7bozzzm/

Comment: Thanks, I didnt saw anywhere in the documents that top and left must be set beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.css()` to adjust a property requires that property to be explicitly set beforehand, whereas `.animate()` will adjust the calculated position of an element without it being specifically set.

In the below snippet, I have given the `#movable` element `top` and `left` properties, and left the other `<div>` without them.  The selector that `.css()` is applied to affects both `<divs>`, but note that only the `<div>` with the `top` and `left` properties moves.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 38)
        {
            $('div').css({top:'-=10px'});
        }
        else if (event.which == 40)
        {
            $('div').css({top:'+=10px'});
        }
        else if (event.which == 37)
        {
            $('div').css({left:'-=10px'});
        }
        else if (event.which == 39)
        {
            $('div').css({left:'+=10px'});
        }
      
      //added to stop Stack Overflow scrolling
      event.preventDefault();
    }); 
  
  
});
```

```css
div {
  position:relative;
}

/* Set top and left of the movable div explicitly */
#movable {
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="movable">movable</div>
<div>immovable</div>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this is arguably a bug in jQuery.  The docs for both `.css()` and `.animate()` say they operate against the "current value", so the behaviour really should be the same.

Comment: `Using .css() to adjust a property requires that property to be explicitly > set beforehand, whereas .animate() will adjust the calculated position of an element without it being specifically set.`

[tag:JamesThorpe] thanks for your answer - this is the reason, I didnt saw this anywhere in the official documents. If I set the top and left properties the code is working. I didnt copy/pasted my CSS but the position of the element was relative. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Moving `div` require space to move or you can use `position:absolute`
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t84q4qkg/)**

Answer (score 1):

Is the code in the post your real code? Because you're using an `event` variable, but you haven't defined any argument to the function passed to `keydown`. It needs to be `$('body').keydown(function(event) {`.

Comment: Could be running in IE - `event` is a global object

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the event but it was working in Chrome too - as James mentioned probably because its global.